# python pointer error: unexpected variable mutation

Tags: python, list, pointers, recursion, mutators

```
def divide_grid():
    G = [[1, 'p'], [2, 'g'], [3, 'r'], [4, 'p']]
    print(G)
    for color in ['p','g']:  
        lst = G
        process(lst)
        print(G)

def process(grid):
    grid[0][1] = 'g'
```

I have this code in python and when I run it,I expect G to remain constant (the same thing should be printed 3 times.)  I was under the impression that python didn't use pointers to variables?  However when i run divide_grid() I get this:

```
[[1, 'p'], [2, 'g'], [3, 'r'], [4, 'p']]
[[1, 'g'], [2, 'g'], [3, 'r'], [4, 'p']]
[[1, 'g'], [2, 'g'], [3, 'r'], [4, 'p']]
```

Why is this happening? How do I fix it so i can edit the process version of grid without changing the original G?  This is a watered down version of my code, for it to work I need to be able to edit and return the grid from this process function without changing the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign G to lst, it is a pointer.

You need to use deepcopy to avoid this:

```
from copy import deepcopy
lst = deepcopy(G)
```

Comment: Only `deepcopy` will work here due to list of lists `copy.copy and [:]`  will not work here